# unable to add classes in react using create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

a bit new to react.
I used the create react app https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app
to start a new react project.

the full code is here.  https://github.com/bryandellinger/reactswitch/tree/master/src

I am trying to get the background color of a selected element to change and the text to become bold but it appears the class is never added not sure what I am doing wrong.

Switch.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import  styles from './Switch.css';

const CREDITCARD = 'Creditcard';
const BTC = 'Bitcoin';


const Choice = function (props) {
  const cssClasses = [];

  if (props.active) {
    // <-- check props, not state
    cssClasses.push(styles.active);
  }

  return (
    <div
      onClick={props.onClick}
      className={cssClasses}
    >
      {props.label} {/* <-- allow any label */}
    </div>
  );
};

class Switch extends React.Component {
  state = {
    payMethod: BTC,
  };

  select = (choice) => {
    return (evt) => {
      this.setState({
        payMethod: choice,
      });
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='switch'>
        <Choice
          onClick={this.select(CREDITCARD)}
          active={this.state.payMethod === CREDITCARD}
          label='Pay with Creditcard'
        />

        <Choice
          onClick={this.select(BTC)}
          active={this.state.payMethod === BTC}
          label='Pay with Bitcoin'
        />

        Paying with: {this.state.payMethod}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Switch;
```

and Switch.css

```
.active {
    background-color: #4619eb;
    font-weight: bold; 
  }
```

it appears the active class from switch.css never gets added on the onclick event. not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way webpack is configured in CRA, you need to write your css like this:

```
 :local(.active) {
    background-color: #4619eb;
    font-weight: bold; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

CRA only supports importing the whole CSS file directly out of the box. So instead of importing the CSS file as a component, you would do:

```
import './Switch.css';
```

CRA docs for adding a stylesheet: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-stylesheet

Also, the className property should be a string with class names separated with a while space. If you want to set the class name dynamically, check out classnames: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames.